# Calculating over time hours for employees against their contract hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

Calculating over time hours for employees against their individual contract hours, the percentage an employee has worked overtimes as well as how many worked more than 10% overtime.

Sample data is here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2ba19/2/0

Sample data has:

```
ID- Employee ID
PROJECT - Project code Employee belongs to
SEGMENT  -  are the projects an employee is working on
SEG_DESC- description of the projects
CONTRACT HRS- is the individual contract hrs the employee is hired to do
HOURS   - are the hours an employee has worked in a segment
TEAM- Employee belongs to
END_OF_WEEK - data is collected weekly
```

I need the
the percentage an employee has worked overtime
how many employees have worked more than 10% overtime

Once these calculations are done, I need to be able to visualise the data in Power BI.

I have actually achieved all I needed to do in Power BI - but the dashboard is extremely slow and therefore not viable. Therefore, the overtime calculations need all to already happen in SQL.
How can I do this?

Please see how it should look:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Anna please provide expected output if possible.

Comment: Make sure your tags are correct.  The fiddle data example uses MySQL 5.6, but you've tagged `sql-server`.

Comment: it needs to be for SQL server NOT mysql

Comment: the sqlfiddle, with database set to MSSQL, is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c04f19/1

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not use images for data. Use formatted text.

Comment: What is the relation from an `employee` to a `team` ?  There is no information for employees given in the pictures.... 

Comment: TEAM- Employee belongs to

Comment: Yes, an employee belongs to a team. If you only share the time that the team has spent, how should be known how much time an individual employee spent?

Comment: .... employee ID `12` and `14` do belong to two teams? or is the data you gave us incorrect ?

Comment: The [percentage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage) in your "how it should look like" is calculated in the incorrect way. It should have been multiplied by 100.

Comment: Nope, data is not incorrect- there are many employees snd many days detention teams. And percent as decimal allows for easier use in other calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your desired output it appears you just need a simple sum of the time per team per Id, in which case the following produces your desired
result:

```
with ot as (
    select *, Sum(hours) over(partition by project, id, team) TimeWorkedPerWeek 
    from workinghours
)
select *, 
    TimeWorkedPerWeek-[contract hrs] OverTimeHours, 
    (TimeWorkedPerWeek)/[CONTRACT HRS]-1 [%Overtime],
    case when TimeWorkedPerWeek> [CONTRACT HRS]*1.1 then 1 else 0 end [Overtime > 10%]
from ot
order by id, team
```

[DBFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c04f19/14)